# Выполнение программы в нескольких потоках

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Хочу написать программу (любую выполняющую какие-либо арифметический действия), но мне нужно, чтобы она выполнялась в нескольких потоках. Подскажите пожалуйста какие стандартные библиотеки есть в С++ (есть ли вообще). И небольшой пример их использования.

Comment: Qt?

Comment: Если есть возможность на Qt, то этот вариант тоже подойдет, но для начала хотелось выполнить задачу на С++

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В boost-е есть библиотека для работы с потоками.
Большим плюсом является то, что она кроссплатформенная.
Документация [тут](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/doc/html/thread.html).
Пример простой программы запускающей один thread:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>  
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

void workerFunc()  
{  
    boost::posix_time::seconds workTime(3);

    std::cout << "Worker: running" << std::endl;

    // Pretend to do something useful...  
    boost::this_thread::sleep(workTime);

    std::cout << "Worker: finished" << std::endl;  
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])  
{  
    std::cout << "main: startup" << std::endl;

    boost::thread workerThread(workerFunc);

    std::cout << "main: waiting for thread" << std::endl;

    workerThread.join();

    std::cout << "main: done" << std::endl;

    return 0;  
}
```

Пример с использованием группы потоков и захватом mutex-а:

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

void print(int* arr, int from, int to) {
    static boost::mutex ioMutex;
    for (int i = from; i < to; ++i) {
        boost::mutex::scoped_lock l(ioMutex);
        std::cout << arr[i] << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() {
    int arr[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    boost::thread_group g;
    g.create_thread(boost::bind(print, arr, 0, 4));
    g.create_thread(boost::bind(print, arr, 4, 8));
    g.join_all();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Хороший пример, спасибо, попробую разобраться

Comment: Еще вопрос: boost же не входит в стандарные библиотеки Linux? Ее нужно добавлять вручную или она называется как-то по-другому?

Comment: Ну в ubuntu, например, достаточно установить libbost-thread-dev(sudo apt-get install libbost-thread-dev), а остальные пакеты пакеты по зависимостям подтянутся. В других дистрибутивах наверное нечто подобное.

Answer (score 3):

openmp
тут на хабре есть пример:

http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/cpp/71296/

UPD:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h> 
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  int i;

  #pragma omp parallel for
  for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
     printf("t#: %i  i: %i\n", omp_get_thread_num(), i);

}
```

на выходе:

```
t#: 2  i: 6
t#: 2  i: 7
t#: 2  i: 8
t#: 3  i: 9
t#: 0  i: 0
t#: 0  i: 1
t#: 0  i: 2
t#: 1  i: 3
t#: 1  i: 4
t#: 1  i: 5
```

Comment: Компилятор не может понять omp_get_thread_num(), если делать     
#pragma omp parallel omp_get_thread_num(3)
сообщение выводится 1 раз.

Comment: какое сообщение? omp_get_thread_num(), насколько я знаю, выводит колчество потоков. 
- omp_get_thread_num(3) это что?

Comment: ошибся, не omp_get_thread_num(3), а  omp_set_num_threads(3). Я понял свою ошибку, у меня не все в порядке с библиотеками, вот компилятор и не видит функций

Answer (score 1):

Используя boost::thread:

```
#include <boost/thread.hpp>

using namespace boost;

void calc0() { 
}

void calc1() { 
}

int main () {
    thread t0 = thread(calc0);
    thread t1 = thread(calc1);

    t0.join();
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

Вычисления проводить в теле функций calc0 и calc1.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно делаю так

```
/*переменные*/
#ifdef _WIN32
    HANDLE thr_handle;
#else
    pthread_t thr_handle; 
    pthread_attr_t attr;    
#endif
/*переменные конец*/
```

Запуск потока

```
/*запуск*/

if (thr_handle != NULL)
{
#ifndef _WIN32
    pthread_join(thr_handle,NULL);
    pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);        
#endif
}
#ifdef _WIN32
    thr_handle = AfxBeginThread(Run, (LPVOID)this, pr, 15000000);
    if (thr_handle == NULL) 
        {сообщаю о жуткой ошибке, типа все плохо}
    else
        {
            return 0;
        }
#else   
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attr, 15000000); 
    if (pthread_create(&thr_handle, &attr, Run, (LPVOID)this) != 0) 
        {сообщаю о жуткой ошибке, типа все плохо}
    else
        {
            return 0;
        }
#endif

/*запуск конец*/
```

В итоге одни раз потоком выполняется функция типа UINT Run(LPVOID pParam)

Если помню правильно, то для сборки: под виндами MFC, под линухом -lpthread

Остальное - мануалка в помощь :)